# How can I move a set of columns that are duplicated down under the matching section?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an export of CSV data that repeats in the columns.  What I need is a clean sheet that has all the columns back together.  I made a mockup; the actual data is much more complicated, and there is a lot more of it.  But this should illustrate what I need.  [image]

I don't control the export so I'm stuck with the data being what it is.  However, it feels like it shouldn't be that hard, almost like Transpose(), but for a set rather than a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `WRAPROWS()` it will be suffice here:

[image]

---

```
=WRAPROWS(A2:I2,3)
```

---

For Older Versions use `INDEX()` Function:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$I$2,,COLUMN(A1)+(ROW(A1)-1)*3)
```

---

However, if there are more data down the line i.e. multiple rows and `#` of columns then use the following:

[image]

---

```
=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A2:I3),3)
```

---

Or,

```
=INDEX($A$2:$I$3,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/3)+1,MOD((COLUMN(A1)+ROW(A1)*3)-4,9)+1)
```

---